# Can a class object created "on the fly" in Kotlin have a constructor?

Tags: android, kotlin, lint

I create an object like this in Kotlin and pass it to my method:

```
    val myObject = object {

        @SerializedName("fieldOne")
        val fieldOne = myFieldOne

        @SerializedName("fieldTwo")
        val fieldTwo = myFieldTwo

        @SerializedName("fieldThree")
        val fieldThree = myFieldThree
    }

    dbManager.save(myObject) // this works fine
```

However, Android Studio complains about it and says:

> Property ''fieldOne'' is never used

I know I could remove this warning via lint options, but would like to find a "native" way to get rid of this warning.

Comment: I think you should change the title of your question, because in the title and the body you ask two completely different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usage of your `object` is done with reflections. The actual class has a constructor defined which has parameter `myFieldOne` to `myFieldThree`.

For the sanity of your code, you should consider using a *data class* instead. *Kotlin* like *Java* is statically typed, which you should leverage as much as possible. The next step would then be to get rid of any reflections you don't need to do.

Comment: Thanks @tynn, data classes seems like the most appropriate option for this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by "native way to get rid of it" but there is an annotation for it:

```
val myObject = @Suppress("unused") object {
    @SerializedName("fieldOne")
    val fieldOne = myFieldOne
    // ...
}
```

Sure, you can create a data class, but there will be use-cases where anonymous singletons (`object {}`) are the better choice and then you will need this annotation to tell the static code analysis that this is desired and not by mistake.

Comment: Yep, `@Suppress("unused")` is part of lint optins I'm not totally convinced to use.

Comment: @lalongooo ok, I see. But as my second paragraph suggests, there are cases in which you will have to use an object{} and thus the notation. I would not change my code design, just because I don't like a Lint warning which can be ignored. Lint can only know so much, it cannot guess your intention, that's why you use annotations "to tell it" to not bother you anymore with things you thought through.

Comment: @lalongooo so if you declare a data class and only use it once, I would rather use the object{}... if you use the data class twice, go with it instead